# How do i set my discord bot's status and presence?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am on the latest version of **discord.js**.
I want to set the activity as `WATCHING Made By -Nightmare <3#9999`.
The presence is working (set as dnd) but the activity is not.

Code as of now:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {   
    console.log('Spectre Is Now Online!');
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "dnd",  
        game: {
            name: "Made By -Nightmare <3#9999",  
            type: "WATCHING" 
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone see where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `setPresence` to set activity. Presence is `online/offline/dnd/away`

What you are looking for is `client.user.setActivity()`

Here is an example of use:

```js
client.user.setActivity('Made By -Nightmare <3#9999', { type: 'WATCHING' })
```

This sets the activity to `Watching Made By -Nightmare <3#9999`

In summary:

```
client.user.setPresence({status: "dnd"}); //sets presence
client.user.setActivity('Made By -Nightmare <3#9999', { type: 'WATCHING' }); //sets activity
```

Comment: Great! No problem

Answer (score 0):

My bot wasn't responding to { type: 'WATCHING' } but does work with this:

`client.user.setActivity('Made By -Nightmare <3#9999', { type: ActivityType.Watching });`

Sidenote, your bot also needs Presence Intent toggled to On in the Discord Developer Portal